# Creating a whitelist of websites on the router

Tags: routing, router

I have a home network using a Siemens SL2-141 ADSL router. Is there a way to tell the router to allow only specific websites, for example, to protect kids using the computers from harmful sites?

I found out that this router can be accessed via telnet, and I found commands to start/stop the ADSL connection, but, I haven't found a way to allow or block specific websites.

Comment: The question is on-topic for [su]; FYI  check out [dansguardian](http://dansguardian.org), it may suit your needs.  Whitelisting is a very labor intensive way to solve your problem

Comment: Does your router allow white lists or child filters? Many ISP's will block harmful content like this, but that depends on whether that has any knock on effect to other users

Comment: @DaveRook I am not sure if there is a built-in whitelist capability. This link: http://patraulea.com/hacks/alice-router-shell/ tells that the router can be accessed with telnet, but I am not sure how it can be programmed further to block/allow sites.

Comment: I'm a little lost why you  are so keen on telnet - telnet is just a way of dialing in, it doesn't give you access to functionality if the router doesn't support it. Personally, as I can't find a solution, I'd consider buying a different router, but one which supports it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution would be setting the DNS server (usually found in configuration settings of the router) to the one which does the needed filtering (one of examples could be OpenDNS, http://www.opendns.com/).

You could set up a similar thing on the router itself, but it is not so straightforward. You will need to install an alternate firmware (like OpenWRT, see http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/gigaset/sl2-141-i) and then set up DNSMasq to only resolve on specified domains.

If you have a Raspberry Pi lying around, you could try if [pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/) can be configured with an allow list, instead of a deny list.

Of course these systems can be fooled if someone sets the DNS server on the computer itself, but while you let the child act only on a limited account that should be OK.

Answer (score -1):

In every router you have a Advance option. Just go to there and look for the option of Block URL or IP select that option and remove your website from block list or put your website in white listing.

Apply group policy or restart the system.

Comment: Blocking some sites is not the same as allowing some sites - which is what the OP asked for. I doubt that they want to type in an almost infinite list of sites that the children should not access; much easier to give a short list of those which they may access